# difference between detect-secrets and detect-secrets-hook results

Tags: devops, credentials

I'm evaluating [detect-secrets](https://github.com/Yelp/detect-secrets) and I'm not sure why I get different results from detect-secrets and the hook.

Here is a log of a simplification:

```
$ cat docs/how-to-2.md
AZ_STORAGE_CS="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storageaccount1234;AccountKey=1OM7c6u5Ocp/zyUMWcRChowzd8czZmxPhzHZ8o45X7tAryr6JFF79+zerFFQS34KzVTK0yadoZGkvZh42A==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
$ detect-secrets scan --string $(cat docs/how-to-2.md)
AWSKeyDetector         : False
ArtifactoryDetector    : False
Base64HighEntropyString: True  (5.367)
BasicAuthDetector      : False
CloudantDetector       : False
HexHighEntropyString   : False
IbmCloudIamDetector    : False
IbmCosHmacDetector     : False
JwtTokenDetector       : False
KeywordDetector        : False
MailchimpDetector      : False
PrivateKeyDetector     : False
SlackDetector          : False
SoftlayerDetector      : False
StripeDetector         : False
TwilioKeyDetector      : False
$ detect-secrets-hook docs/how-to-2.md
$ detect-secrets-hook --baseline .secrets.baseline docs/how-to-2.md
```

I would have expected that `detect-secrets-hook` would tell me about that Azure storage account key that has high entropy.

more details about the baseline:

```
$ cat .secrets.baseline
{
  "custom_plugin_paths": [],
  "exclude": {
    "files": null,
    "lines": null
  },
  "generated_at": "2020-10-09T10:06:54Z",
  "plugins_used": [
    {
      "name": "AWSKeyDetector"
    },
    {
      "name": "ArtifactoryDetector"
    },
    {
      "base64_limit": 4.5,
      "name": "Base64HighEntropyString"
    },
    {
      "name": "BasicAuthDetector"
    },
    {
      "name": "CloudantDetector"
    },
    {
      "hex_limit": 3,
      "name": "HexHighEntropyString"
    },
    {
      "name": "IbmCloudIamDetector"
    },
    {
      "name": "IbmCosHmacDetector"
    },
    {
      "name": "JwtTokenDetector"
    },
    {
      "keyword_exclude": null,
      "name": "KeywordDetector"
    },
    {
      "name": "MailchimpDetector"
    },
    {
      "name": "PrivateKeyDetector"
    },
    {
      "name": "SlackDetector"
    },
    {
      "name": "SoftlayerDetector"
    },
    {
      "name": "StripeDetector"
    },
    {
      "name": "TwilioKeyDetector"
    }
  ],
  "results": {
    ".devcontainer/Dockerfile": [
      {
        ###obfuscated###
      }
    ],
    "deployment/export-sp.sh": [
      {
        ###obfuscated###
      }
    ],
    "docs/pip-install-from-artifacts-feeds.md": [
      {
        ###obfuscated###
      }
    ]
  },
  "version": "0.14.3",
  "word_list": {
    "file": null,
    "hash": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely peculiar behavior, but after some investigation, I realize that you've stumbled upon an edge case of the tool.

#### tl;dr

- `HighEntropyStringPlugin` supports a limited set of characters (not including `;`)
- To reduce false positives, `HighEntropyStringPlugin` leverages the heuristic that strings are quoted in certain contexts.
- To improve UI, inline string scanning does **not** require quoted strings.

Therefore, the functionality differs: when run through `detect-secrets-hook`, it does not parse the string accordingly due to the existence of `;`. However, when run through `detect-secrets scan --string`, it does not require quotes, and breaks the string up.

#### Detailed Explanation

HighEntropyString tests are pretty noisy, if not aggressively pruned for false positives. One way it attempts to do this is via applying a rather strict regex ([source](https://github.com/Yelp/detect-secrets/blob/master/detect_secrets/plugins/high_entropy_strings.py#L409-L415)), which [requires it to be inside quotes](https://github.com/Yelp/detect-secrets/blob/master/detect_secrets/plugins/high_entropy_strings.py#L38). However, for certain contexts, [this quoted requirement is removed](https://github.com/Yelp/detect-secrets/blob/master/detect_secrets/plugins/high_entropy_strings.py#L179-L201) (e.g. YAML files, and inline string scanning).

When this quoted requirement is removed, we get the following breakdown:

```
>>> line = 'AZ_STORAGE_CS="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storageaccount1234;AccountKey=1OM7c6u5Ocp/zyUMWcRChowzd8czZmxPhzHZ8o45X7tAryr6JFF79+zerFFQS34KzVTK0yadoZGkvZh42A==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"'
>>> with self.non_quoted_string_regex(is_exact_match=False):
...    self.regex.findall(line)
['AZ_STORAGE_CS=', 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https', 'AccountName=storageaccount1234', 'AccountKey=1OM7c6u5Ocp/zyUMWcRChowzd8czZmxPhzHZ8o45X7tAryr6JFF79+zerFFQS34KzVTK0yadoZGkvZh42A==', 'EndpointSuffix=core', 'windows', 'net']
```

When we do so, we can see that the `AccountKey=1OM7c6u5Ocp/zyUMWcRChowzd8czZmxPhzHZ8o45X7tAryr6JFF79+zerFFQS34KzVTK0yadoZGkvZh42A==` would trigger the base64 plugin, as demonstrated below:

```
$ detect-secrets scan --string 'AccountKey=1OM7c6u5Ocp/zyUMWcRChowzd8czZmxPhzHZ8o45X7tAryr6JFF79+zerFFQS34KzVTK0yadoZGkvZh42A=='
AWSKeyDetector         : False
ArtifactoryDetector    : False
Base64HighEntropyString: True  (5.367)
BasicAuthDetector      : False
CloudantDetector       : False
HexHighEntropyString   : False
IbmCloudIamDetector    : False
IbmCosHmacDetector     : False
JwtTokenDetector       : False
KeywordDetector        : False
MailchimpDetector      : False
PrivateKeyDetector     : False
SlackDetector          : False
SoftlayerDetector      : False
StripeDetector         : False
TwilioKeyDetector      : False
```

However, when this quoted requirement **is** applied, then the entire string payload is scanned as one potential secret: `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storageaccount1234;AccountKey=1OM7c6u5Ocp/zyUMWcRChowzd8czZmxPhzHZ8o45X7tAryr6JFF79+zerFFQS34KzVTK0yadoZGkvZh42A==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net`

This doesn't get flagged because it fails the original base64 regex rules, which doesn't know how to handle `;`.

```
>>> self.regex.findall(line)
[]
```

Therefore, this functionality differs, though, not immediately apparent through the invocation pattern described.

#### How Do I Fix This?

This is a much more challenging question, since allowing other characters would change the entropy calculation, and the probability of flagging strings. There has been some discussion around creating a plugin for all characters, but the team has not yet been able to decide on a default entropy limit for this.

Comment: Would the right way to have an Azure storage key detected be to develop a plugin?

Comment: Yeah. `detect-secrets` does allow you to specify custom plugins, which makes this process a little easier though.